# PHP force download "zz" apears before file text

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to have a PHP file force download txt,php,html & css files, But when its downloaded "zz" appears before the content of the file.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$file = "../files/".$_GET["f"]; 

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET["f"]); 

readfile($file); 
?>
```

Comment: zz is inside the file when you open it with a text editor? Quick side note it that I can download any file on your server if I just so happen to pass the right f=____ in my URL.

Comment: @stomo21, Yes it appears inside the text file after i download it.
Security is not an issue right now, As this is for private use only